# Black screen without cursor after choosing Ubuntu from grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have dualboot windows 11 and Ubuntu and when I choose Ubuntu from the grub menu it only displays a dark screen.  Windows turns on normally. I was looking for an answer here but found nothing.  I don't have error messages, the only thing I can give is a picture of what is displayed.  If somebudy needs more information, write and I will try to send it. [photo of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QIFi.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: No, it doesn't repair, I tried unless I'm doing something wrong

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? What is the GPU?

Comment: GPU - NVIDIA GeForce 730, Ubuntu 20.04 Lts

Comment: So boot with `nomodeset` and install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: When I set nomodeset as in this questions you sent it still didnt turn on

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be due to the installation as Ubuntu has been crushing for a while. After a while it stopped by itself, but after the error I encountered now I found that I would not bother anymore and using DiskInternals Linux Reader I moved the more important files to Windows and uninstalled ubuntu.